# Abort searches on Alfresco

Tags: ajax, search, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a customised Alfresco Community installation. I have a lot of documents, so it's normal that some searches take a couple of seconds to perform.

I can see the AJAX calls triggered by Alfresco, on my web inspector.

Now, if I trigger a search, and then immediately change the search terms and trigger another search, there are two AJAX requests. Sometimes I can see the results of the second search being rendered (as it was a faster search), then a couple of seconds later, the results of the first search are rendered (the slowest one).

What is the elegant way to ask Alfresco to abort any pending searches before performing new ones?

Answer (score 6):

You will have to extend Share's search component (JavaScript) and use YUI XHRDataSource + set connXhrMode:

> **queueRequests**
>   If a request is already in progress, wait until response is returned before sending the next request.
>
> **cancelStaleRequests**
>   If a request is already in progress, cancel it before sending the next request.
>
> **ignoreStaleResponses**
>   Send all requests, but handle only the response for the most recently sent request.
>
> **allowAll**
>   Send all requests and handle all responses.

http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/datasource/index.html#xhr

Comment: Interesting the Datasource supports that. Functions in Alfresco.util.Ajax don't seem to expose similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in your GUI rather than Alfresco or any other backend system.

It's good common architecture where you can handle multiple requests.

If it's only an issue where rendering is the problem, then change the JavaScript YUI methods which renders the requests and just built-in checks to invalidate the old request to render.

Comment: The GUI is the standard GUI. And you just told me to do something, that I asked on the first place help on how to do it. :)